Sheet metal screws holding ceiling drywall. How to I find the heads?
Live in a condo.  I need to access area above drop ceiling.  Ceiling drywall is attached to metal frame with sheet metal screws.  I cut a 8x8” hole in the drywall to see why larger access piece was not dropping down. Upon sticking my head through the hole I realized the drywall is fastened to metal ceiling frame.  I can see the pointy ends of the sheet metal screws, but the heads are hidden in the texture of the drywall.  How do I:  find the heads of the screws to unscrew the drywall?  Or is it possible to use a hole saw from above the drywall in the area above the drop ceiling? ‍♀️

How big a hole do you need?

Try using a magnetic stud finder to determine where the screw heads are. If you don't plan on using the same drywall to repair the ceiling, just rip it down. The screw heads will just rip through the drywall and you can then remove them from the metal framing.  It will probably be faster than locating and removing the screws, depending on the amount you have to remove. You can also just scrape the texture off the ceiling and locate the screws that way.

Rare earth (strong) magnet. I tend to use old hard drive magnets, but any really strong magnet will find the screw head beneath the joint compound.
